# Using Apache POI WordToHtmlConverter to get the text of a document

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have some software that is converting a Word Document to HTML.  What I need is a way to get just the text of the document.  Below is a sample of my code.  When the doc is converted to html it seems the doc is written to html tags .  I don't have much experiance with html and web developement.  I am mostly an app and desktop developer.  What is a simple way to get just the paragraph text.  Below is the code I have so far.  I need to get the info as a string so I can parse it.

```
private void convertWordDoctoHTML(File file) throws ParserConfigurationException, TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerException, IOException {
    HWPFDocumentCore wordDocument = null;
    try {
        wordDocument = WordToHtmlUtils.loadDoc(new FileInputStream(file));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
    }

    WordToHtmlConverter wordToHtmlConverter = new WordToHtmlConverter(DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument());
    wordToHtmlConverter.processDocument(wordDocument);
    org.w3c.dom.Document htmlDocument = wordToHtmlConverter.getDocument();
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(htmlDocument);
    StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(out);

    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer serializer = tf.newTransformer();
    serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
    serializer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
    out.close();

    String result = new String(out.toByteArray());
    System.out.println(result);
    docEditorPane.setPage(selectedFile.toURI().toURL());
    newDocText = result;
}
```

Comment: If you only want the text, why not use the POI provided Word -> Plain Text converter / text extractor instead?

Comment: I need to preserve the layout of the document and that's why I am converting the document to a HTML file.  That was the quickest way.

Comment: So do you have any idea how to get the text.

Comment: What are you after then? Just the HTML that makes up the body? Plain text of the body, split by paragraph, with no html formatting? Something else? It sounds like you want more than just the text, so you'll need to be more specific on your exact requirements!

Comment: Well I am going to open the doc and make changes through string manipulation then save out the document as a html so I can preserve the tables and other images on the doc.  Outside of changing the text I need to preserve the document as much as possible.